# IFCjs: Viewer: How to change onHover color?

Tags: ifc

I would like to change the color of the onHover effect in IFCjs viewer. Currently it is pink, it would be nice if it was lightGrey.
Can anybody help me do it?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Try this (change the preselectMat as you wish):

```
const preselectMat = new MeshLambertMaterial({
transparent: true,
opacity: 0.9,
color: 0xff0000,
depthTest: true,
});

viewer.IFC.selector.preselection.material = preselectMat
```